# What is this thermal insulating material?

Tags: heating-systems, thermal-insulation

I need to thermally insulate measurement chamber heated to 70°C. Material used for this task needs to be also electrically insulating. I tried various materials, but result was always clumsy and unconvincing. I found piece of white sheet/foil (picture) in some old product that may be suitable for this, but I'm unable to identify this material. It's soft, porous, about 3mm thick, there is adhesive pad on one side of this, surface on other side is smooth. What is it?

[image]

Comment: go to a plumbing supply store and look for hot water pipe insulation

Answer (score 0):

It is probably foamed polyethylene. Similar products are commonly used to seal up air leaks around house windows and doors, and to fill gaps between a pickup truck bed and a camper shell. It is generically known as *foam weatherstripping* and is sold as rolled-up tape of various widths and thicknesses in hardware and auto supply stores.
.

Comment: also used for packaging fragile items and for insulating hot water pipes in homes